# Remove extra padding/margin from TextInputLayout setError text

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am using TextInputLayout to show error with EditText. All is working good. I have to remove extra space from TextInputLayout's error text.

So far I had did this,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/txt_error_passowrd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/EditHintText">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/views_height"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/light_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_14sp" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And inside style.xml I had use this

```
 <style name="EditHintText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_10sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_text_color</item>
</style>

<style name="error_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_10sp</item>
</style>
```

I have attached [image: screen shot]. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this line ***android:paddingLeft=10dp*** from TextInputEditText, as there is no padding in TextInputLayout this EditText padding may be causing the problem also why are you using ***android:layout_weight=1*** for TextInputLayout when none of its height or width is set to 0dp.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the extra padding by using `app:hintEnabled="false"` in TextInputLayout. But using it will prevent the hint from going above because the extra space was meant for the hint text when it goes above.

Answer (score 1):

For general cases of TextInputLayout, you can set error padding like this:

```
 { your TextInputLayout }.apply {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
                if (childCount > 1) {
                    getChildAt(1)?.let {
                        it.setPadding(
                            yourPaddingStart,
                            yourPaddingTop,
                            yourPaddingRight,
                            yourPaddingBottom
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As usually TextInputLayout structure is like image below:

[TextInputLayout common structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9plU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line only and work like charm`android:paddingLeft=10dp`

Answer (score 0):

If you set paddings in the code, then they will not affect on error-view paddings.
in layout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout  
    ...
    >
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        ...
        tools:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/input_horizontal_padding"
        tools:paddingVertical="@dimen/input_vertical_padding"
    />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

in code

```
val paddingHorizontal = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.input_horizontal_padding)
val paddingVertical = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.input_vertical_padding)
editText.setPadding(paddingHorizontal, paddingVertical, paddingHorizontal, paddingVertical)
```